# What precedes and follows: triangle, tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have not studied geometry beyond high school myself. I’m looking for an answer that would satisfy (and be understood by) lower secondary school students.

---

**Given that ...**

Using straight lines, you need three lines to make the “simplest” closed object (polygon) in 2D space: a triangle.

Using flat surfaces, you need four surfaces to make the “simplest” closed object (polyhedron) in 3D space: a tetrahedron.

**does it precede that ...**

Using [?] points, you need two points to make the “simplest” closed object ([?]) in 1D space: a [?].

**and follow that ...**

Using [?] volumes, you need five volumes to make the “simplest” closed object ([?]) in 4D space: a [?].

**and what terms can fill in the [?] blanks?**

Comment: There is a nice pattern to consider;  It takes 2 points to make a line segment, 3 line segments to make a triangle, 4 triangles to make a tetrahedron....  can you extend to say that it takes 4 tetrahedron to make a _______.  Visit [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) for more information

Comment: You might be thinking of an "[interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))" for the 1-dimensional case, but that depends on what you consider to be an "object."  Arguably a point is simpler.  As for extending to higher dimensions, the more general term you are after is "[polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-polytope)" (*polygons are 2-dimensional polytopes, while polyhedrons are 3-dimensional polytopes*).  Tessaracts are easy examples of a 4-dimensional polytope, but the [5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell) is the example with fewest hyperplanes making it.

Comment: I guess ‘flat’ and ‘straight’ don’t devolve any further into anything. I think you’re right on 1D: two points “close” an “interval” in 1D space. Reading Wikipedia on 5-cell ... seems like the candidate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general concept is called a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex). The pattern goes:

- A **point** is a 0D figure.
- Two points can be the vertices of a **line segment**, which is a 1D figure. The boundary of a line segment consists of two **points** which are called its **endpoints**.
- Three points can be the vertices of a **triangle**, which is a 2D figure, and the simplest **polygon**. The boundary of a triangle consists of three **line segments** which are called its **edges**.
- Four points can be the vertices of a **tetrahedron**, which is a 3D figure, and the simplest **polyhedron**. The boundary of a tetrahedron consists of four **triangles** which are called its **faces**.
- Five points can be the vertices of a **pentachoron**, which is a 4D figure, and the simplest **polychoron**. The boundary of a pentachoron consists of five **tetrahedra** which are called its **cells**.
- ...
- 100 points can be the vertices of a **99-simplex**, which is a 99D figure, and the simplest **99-polytope**. The boundary of a 99-simplex consists of 100 **98-simplices** which are called its **facets**.
- ...

You can take the 99-simplex example and extend it backwards, too. A pentachoron is a 4-simplex, a tetrahedron is a 3-simplex, a triangle is a 2-simplex, a line segment is a 1-simplex, and a point is a 0-simplex.

Comment: I’ll take this as the answer. You gave terms for the sequence, including names of the objects and their “endpoints”, which are all easy to follow.